# Meteor:reactiveTable adding data dynamically

Tags: meteor

I am using reactiveTable in my application:

table.html:

```
{{> reactiveTable collection=tables settings=tableSettings}}
```

How do I populate this table dynamically?

Comment: The table will automatically update as documents in the `tables` collection are added/updated/removed. Do you have a `tables` collection in your model?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Did not realize tables is a reactive var.